# Using default "timezone.now" method in forms. --- TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am Building a BlogApp and I am working on a Feature BUT i am stuck on a Error.
I made `date = forms.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)` BUT it is keep showing me :-

> TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'default'

**What i am trying to do**

I want it to set default time of now in the `form field` in the Browser.

forms.py

```
from django.utils import timezone

class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    date = forms.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ('post_title','date',)
        widgets = {'post_title': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols':50})}
```

models.py

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    post_owner = models.ForeignKey(User,default='',null=True,on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    post_title = models.CharField(max_length=500,default='')
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(null=True,default=timezone.now)
```

**What have i tried**

I also tried `default method` in models , it is working fine BUT i want to make a `Validation Error` which i cannot do in `model` It is only possible in Forms . So i am doing it in Forms.

I don't know what to do.

Any help would be Appreciated.

Thank You in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django form fields don't accept a `default` argument. However, to supply an initial value, you can use the `initial` parameter:

```
date = forms.DateTimeField(initial=timezone.now)
```

Comment: Thanks . It Worked